# ASP.NET MVC How may I register a resource file in my view folder, to be used as @using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view I would like to reference a resource file which is placed in my view folder.

I've tried to set this in the view heading:

```
@using SolutionName.Areas.Main.Views
```

but Only the controller and model are shown by intellisense

```
SolutionName.Areas.Main.Controller
SolutionName.Areas.Main.Model
```

How may I get the View folder to be listed as well?

Comment: Are you sure that your resource file is under the `SolutionName.Areas.Main.Views` namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply bring the namespace into scope:

```
@using MyResources = SolutionName.Areas.Main.Views
```

and then whenever you want to use that resource file you can simply write as below:

```
@MyResources.String1
```

For more information :-

http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/

**Update** :-

And set  properties as shown in below figure :-

[image]

Comment: I found the information I was looking for in the url you provided. Thanks! By setting CustomTool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator in the resx property. I was originally set to ResXFileCodeGenerator.